# Subquery and correlated query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

The database is:

Highschooler ( ID, name, grade ) English: There is a high school student with unique ID and a given first name in a certain grade.

Friend ( ID1, ID2 ) English: The student with ID1 is friends with the student with ID2. Friendship is mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Friend table, so is (456, 123).

Likes ( ID1, ID2 ) English: The student with ID1 likes the student with ID2. Liking someone is not necessarily mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Likes table, there is no guarantee that (456, 123) is also present.

The task is to: Find names and grades of students who only have friends in the same grade. Return the result sorted by grade, then by name within each grade.

One Commands are :

```
select distinct name, grade
from Highschooler s1
where not exists (select * from Highschooler s2 join Friend on (Friend.ID2 = s2.ID)
                  where s1.ID = Friend.ID1 
                  and s2.grade <> s1.grade)
 order by grade, name
```

The second commands are:

```
select distinct name, grade
from Highschooler s1 join Friend on (Friend.ID1 = s1.ID)
where not exists (select * from Highschooler s2
                   where Friend.ID2 = s2.ID
                  and s2.grade <> s1.grade)
 order by grade, name
```

Both of these commands says we want to find out Highschooler with friends only in the same grades. But the results are different. Which one is correct and WHAT IS THE OTHER ONE TELL US ABOUT? I will really appreciate it if some experts can provide some explanations,

Comment: No they are not similar. One is proper join in inner query while other is corelated query.

Comment: No, these queries are not the same., they are completely different. In the first a subquery contains join of two tables, the second one retrieves data only from one table.

Comment: You are using `not exists` rather than `exists`, so logic in the subquery gets all inverted.  The queries are different.  And, neither is the way that I would approach the problem.

Comment: @kordirko   What do these queries tell us then?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thank you for your kind comments. Do you have some better way of doing the query? Which one above do you think is the right one and why is the other one wrong?

Comment: @SMA I know but what is the other one tell us about then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out Highscooler with friends and the **same** grade, I think you need this:

```
select distinct s1.name, s1.grade
from Highschooler s1 
join Friend on (Friend.ID1 = s1.ID or Friend.ID2 = s1.ID)
join Highschooler s2 on ((Friend.ID1 = s2.ID and Friend.ID2 = s1.ID) or (Friend.ID1 = s1.ID and Friend.ID2 = s2.ID)) /* sent or received request */
where s1.grade = s2.grade /* same grade */
order by s1.grade, s1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as an aggregation.  I just find it easier to follow the logic.  Take the `friend` table and look up the grades of each friend.  Then aggregate by the first friend and use a `having` clause to determine if any of the friends are from another grade:

```
select hs1.*
from friend f join
     highschooler hs1
     on f.id1 = hs1.id join
     highschooler hs2
     on f.id2 = hs2.id
group by hs1.id
having sum(hs1.grade <> hs2.grade) = 0;
```